# Time cannot be set in the past condition Python

Tags: python-3.x

**What I need to do.**
I need this program to not allow a user to input a date that's in the past. when I try it as it currently is i get the following error message. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
def addNewItems():
        end = 4
        while end == 4:
            ToDoList = [ ]
            Name = input("Enter the name of your task")
            dateIn = input("Enter the task completion date. yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS")
            date = datetime.strptime(dateIn, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
            now = datetime.now()
            now_ = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
            if date < now_:
                print("Time entered is in the past! Select options again")
                continue
            if Name in ToDoList:
                print("Task already exists! Select options again")
                continue
            if date < now_ and Name not in ToDoList:
                ToDoList.append(Name, date)
                print("Task Added Sucessfully")
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need two `datetime` objects to use the `<` comparison directly.

You just need to compare `date` with `now`, intead of `date` with `now_` in order to do what you want.

And just an advice. You're importing `date` from `datetime` library, so you should avoid creating variables with the same name if you intend calling the original `date` somewhere else in your code